# How to merge from upstream branch?

Tags: windows, git, branching-and-merging, smartgit

Here is my git setup (we use Git + Atlassian Stash in our corporate network):

```
upstream:
  master

origin (my fork of 'upstream'):
  master
  branch1 (branch of master, with a few commits on top of it)

clone (local; clone of 'origin'):
  master
  branch1 (ahead of 'origin:branch1' by 1 commit)
```

What I want to do:

I want to merge `upstream:master -> clone:branch1`. I know there will be conflicts with this merge (since I changed files in my `branch1` that others have changed in upstream). Once this is done I hope to push my changes back to `origin:branch1`, which will include my 1 commit + latest base from upstream (I want to keep up to date with the `master` branch, since that's the one I branched from). Along with this I want it to be a rebase, so that the commit history is clean and doesn't spider-web all over the place.

Another note is that I do not use git command line directly. On Windows, I'm using SmartGit, so if anyone knows instructions for that tool that would be most ideal.

How can I properly merge like I have described above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no one else has cloned or is working with branch1, you can **[rebase](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/documentation/4.6/show?page=commands-branch#rebase)** it on top of master, once you have updated master to upstream/master.

- First, [fetch `upstream`](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/documentation/4.6/show?page=commands#pull) (SmartGit: Remote/Pull, select "Fetch Only")
- Then reset `master` to `upstream/master` (SmartGit: Local/Reset)
- Now rebase branch1 on top of master (SmartGit: In the `Branches` view, you can right-click on a branch like `master` and select `Rebase HEAD` to rebase your current HEAD onto the selected branch `master`)
  [Resolve merge conflicts](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/documentation/4.6/show?page=commands-branch#resolve-conflicts) if necessary.
- Finally push (force the push) of `branch1` to `origin` (SmartGit: In the context menu of the `Branches` view, you can invoke `Push` and `Push To` on local branches).

[image]

Comment: The rebase terminology is confusing and somewhat scary. I see "rebase onto the selected branch", and since `master` is the branch I'm "selecting", it makes it sound like I'm merging `branch1` into `master`. Am I reading this backwards?

Comment: Think of "rebase onto" as "replay after", e.g. "replay commits from `branch1` after commits in `master`".

Comment: @dahlbyk To me that means "Take commits from `branch1` and put them into `master`". Is this correct? I want to do the opposite... I want the latest changes in `master` to be placed into `branch1` (to keep up with latest progress in the original mainline).

Comment: *onto* not *into*. `master` stays the same; `branch1` changes to start from `master` and then changes are applied from there.

Comment: @dahlbyk Sorry for complicating what seems to be minor, but he said "rebase `branch1` on top of `master`". To me this should read "rebase `master` on top of `branch1`", which is effectively making `branch1` the target of the rebase (which it is). The way I'm reading it makes it sound like "The chair jumped onto the dog" (doesn't make sense), instead of "The dog jumped onto the chair" (makes sense).

Comment: @RobertDailey what I propose it to replay `branch1` on top of `master` (`rebase master`) rather than merging `master` back to `branch1`. This is what it detailed in https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorial/rewriting-git-history#!rebase.

Comment: @VonC The git tutorial you linked really helped put it into perspective. However, if you rebase doesn't that basically make you lose information about *when* you branched? So in other words, when you merge the feature (branch1) back to master, there will be no commits on master between the start of branch1 and the end of it?

Comment: @RobertDailey with a *distributed* VCS, the goal isn't to see when you merge, but to see a coherent sequence of commits. The goal of a rebase, followed by a merge to master, is to have that `branch1` sequence integrated on top of the most recent `master`. The **"when" which matters** it *not* when you *started*, but when you *integrated back* your feature branch, because that is when *others* will be impacted by it.

Comment: Note that @VonC's stance (with which I agree) is not necessarily how everyone uses DVCSes. Some will happy merge from master into feature branches, and then merge back into master. Personally, I like to think of my feature branches as "changes since `master`" and as `master` shifts over time, my branch does as well.